# Calcular fechas en Excel

Tags: excel, date, vba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Sabemos que para restar fechas, es solamente restar la Fmayor de la Fmenor.
Y estas formulas funcionan en una celda.

¿Existe alguna formula realice "todo en una celda", es decir calcular la diferencia entre las columnas, Y NO estar copiando la formula en cada celda y despues realizar la suma como se realiza comunmente? ¿O algun script que se ejecute al modificar una celda, como se realiza en VBA?

Muchas gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Se puede obtener el resultado de restas de fechas entre 2 columnas, con una sola formula sin necesidad de hacerlo fila por fila y luego realizar la suma para obtener el total. Se que se puede con la funcion .SI dejando como variable que sean mayores menores o iguales a cierta fecha, NO necesito eso, solamente quiero restar datos entre 2 columnas y obtener el total de dias que existe entre ellas. Deje otra imagen, espero lo explique mejor

Comment: Agregaste capturas de pantalla, pero hasta ahora no estás mencionando con qué lenguaje(s) estás trabajando, ni has mostrado qué has intentado hasta el momento. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega esa información relevante en tu pregunta, además de agregar las etiquetas correspondientes.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es poner la fórmula en una celda y arrastrar el cuadradito del inferior derecho de la selección a todas las celdas que quieras y se aplicará la misma fórmula, conservando la posición relativa. Puedes plantearlo mejor?

Comment: Copiar y arrastrar la formula en una columna, y luego sumar el total, es sencillo. Tambien seria mas sencillo si fueran numeros o valores, pero son Fechas. Lo que quiero es una sola formula, en una sola celda, o un Script que te ahorre ese trabajo

Comment: estoy seguro de que la comunidad tiene el animo de ayudarte, pero tu pregunta no encaja en el enfoque del sitio, ya que las formulas de excel, a menos que estes implementando un macro en VB, no son un problema de programacion ...

Comment: estoy seguro que tu pregunta y dudas seran mejor recibidas en el sitio [SQA](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel)

Comment: En VBA puedes crearte una función que, dado un rango de fechas (B:C), te haga las operaciones y te devuelva la suma de todas las operaciones.  Pero claro, algo tienes que aportar tú. Intenta crear esa función y, si falla el proceso, actualiza tu pregunta, añade el código que has montado y vemos cómo ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, la verdad, es que hace mucho ya no utilizo ni Excel ni VBA , migre a las Googlesheet, por eso pido ayuda para crear un SCRIPT

Comment: Gracias Esei por tu respuesta, SUMA Y SUMAPRODUCTO Funcionan perfecto, ahora la pongo un poco mas complicada, es sumar los dias.lab.de las columnas. ej DIAS.LAB.INTL((A:A);(B:B);"0000011"),

Comment: JuanSalinas: Aunque esta pregunta ya tiene una respuesta aceptada, creo que vale la pena hacer mención que en Excel, como en Google Sheets, y otras hojas de cálculo, hay muchas cosas que se pueden hacer tanto usando fórmulas como usando código. Esta pregunta debería ser específica incluso con respecto a si se ha de usar fórmulas o código, los datos se deberían agregar en formato de texto en lugar de imágenes, y deberías mostrar lo que has intentado. P.D. Además de VBA, si cuentas con la plataforma correspondiente, se puede usar JavaScript en Excel y recientemente incorporó el soporte de Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres es sumar el total de diferencias de días entre cada pareja de fechas, ahorrándote la columna auxiliar. Se puede hacer perfectamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fórmula utilizada en Excel es `=SUMA(B3:B9-A3:A9)`. Dependiendo de tu versión de Excel, pudiera ser que en vez de SUMA necesites SUMAPRODUCTO así: `=SUMAPRODUCTO(B3:B9-A3:A9)`

Comment: Gracias Esei por tu respuesta, SUMA Y SUMAPRODUCTO Funcionan perfecto, ahora la pongo un poco mas complicada, es sumar los dias.lab.de las columnas. ej DIAS.LAB.INTL((A:A);(B:B);"0000011")

Comment: @JuanSalinas Las preguntas de seguimiento deberían publicarse como una nueva pregunta en lugar de preguntar en comentarios. Los comentarios en pricipio sólo deben de usarse para pedir aclaraciones y dar sugerencias sobre como mejorar una publicación.

Comment: @JuanSalinas Nuevas preguntas requieren nuevos hilos. Abre una nueva pregunta, aporta datos de ejemplo que se puedan copiar y pegar y pon también lo que has intentado y el resultado que esperas,